Unable to connect to the EMQX broker from PLC via LMQTT library
I need to set up MQTT communication with an EMQX broker via TLS, but when I try to connect to the broker, I get error 16#8730 and diagnostics subfunction 5. According to the documentation, the error lies in non-authorization (incorrect password or username), but I'm pretty sure I have the correct credentials. I protect the project with security and added a CA certificate downloaded from EMQX.
(EMQX certificate (CA) I added to the Certification Manager into Certificate Authority (CA) tab. Later I found out that in the MQTT example they added certificate into Trusted certificate and root certificates tab. Could this be causing this problem?)
Information:
PLC: S7-1200, firmware v4.5
LMQTT 4.0.2, TIA Portal v17.

In the attached image, you can see my LMQTT configuration.
(I tried to set keepAlive or willTopic, but it still doesn't work.)
Thanks for help!


Please ensure you can connect with a tool like MQTTX using the same broker, username and password. With the default emqx cloud setup you should not need a client certificate (I'd expect a different error if this was a TLS issue).

@Brits Hi! Yes, I am sure that it works. I already have Java/Kotlin application as consumer connected to the broker and Python script for sending dummy data. This works well. Only PLC is unable to connect.
I think too, that for default cloud setup client certificate isn't necessary, but broker certificate yes. My python doesn't work without CA broker certificate.

Correct - the broker cert (or the CA cert that signed it) is required to verify that the cert the server presents is valid (assuming validateServerIdentity is true) - it this were an issue I would expect a different error. I cannot see anything obviously wrong (but have not used this PLC). Unfortunately I don't think EMQX cloud provides access to logs, it might be worth spinning up a local instance (either EMQX or Mosquitto) and seeing what the PLC is sending in the CONNECT packet.

After an extensive investigation, I found that the PLC S7-1200 does not support TLS with SNI. However, most cloud serverless brokers, such as HiveMQ and EMQX, require SNI support.
The solution is to create a custom broker (for example, Mosquitto) and set up TLS without SNI. I've successfully set up Mosquitto on my Raspberry Pi with a static IP, and it now works flawlessly.

Wow, thats an somewhat unexpected (but documented here). Acccepting the TLS connection and returning error 5 (not authorized) means the cause is somewhat obscured.

Yes, unfortunately. Hope in the future firmware versions it will be fixed :) For now only S7-1500 with specific firmware version supports TLS with SNI

Shame on me.  I was going to comment to look up restrictions with TLS and S7-1200.  I didn't have exactly that issue, but I had an issue with 'custom' token exchange employed by Microsoft TDS not being accepted by my S7-1500, which expected a 'standard' token exchange.  Rule-of-thumb: if it's not OPC/UA, approach secure communication between Siemens and 3rd party devices with extreme caution and do your homework first.
